# Bootstrap responsive layout is breaking on small screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

For normal and high resolution screens it displays fine, but on small resolution screens it breaks. I tried using classes like `col-xs-12` but it still did not display properly.

```html
<div class="container-fluid about-page-background">
  <div class="container" style="height: 289px; margin-top: 60px; padding-left: 60px; padding-right: 60px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 about-staf">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        <span>consectetur adipisicing elit, sed</span>
        <span>do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut</span>
        <span>labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 about-join">
        <span>Ut enim ad?</span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning join-button">minim veniam,
quis</a>
        <span class="volunteer-info">nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris<a href="#"> laboris nisi ut aliquip</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 about-text">
        <span>
                ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        </span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span>proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The full code [can be viewed on plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/irhVXK6Hg9yVObNZxkcr?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given fixed `height: 600px` to the div. So when changing the width, content should automatically adjust to the space and will go down.

You can only do onething, if you want the hieght to be fixed 600px, do **`meadia query`**. Using media query reduce font size and padding.

for example:

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .container{
   padding: 1em !important;
  }
  .col-md-8.col-xs-12.about-staf span{
   font-size: 27px;
  }
}
```

**Note:** all the classes above are from your plunkr only.

like this reduce width of `button`, font size, other paddings etc

Comment: yes, i remove fixed height, but it looks fine on normal, large and xs view. on small view text superimposed on each other. but I made settings col-xs-12 and if I right sm = 12 too, or not?

Comment: col-xs-12 is saying that the div should have max-width (12 grids) in extra small devices. that is working fine. but anyway your text's font size is very large. it could not occupy the space available (even though 12 grids are provided). So you have to use media query to reduce font size and padding